# How do you set C++11 as default in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Is it possible to avoid having to go to project settings and add a compilation flag to use C++11 for every project I create in eclipse and just make C++11 the default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it the default in a given workspace, by going to `Preferences -> C/C++ -> Build -> Settings -> Discovery -> CDT [Your Compiler] Built-in Compiler Settings`, and adding `-std=c++11` to the `Command to get compiler specs` there.

Note that, in order for a project to pick up this workspace-wide settings, in the project's `Properties -> C/C++ General -> Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros etc. -> Providers -> CDT [Your Compiler] Built-in Compiler Settings`, `Use global provider shared between projects` needs to be checked.

Comment: Is there any way to make "Use global provider shared between projects" the default?